# Is it wrong to connect the red ceiling wire to the blue wire on my receiver for the remote and the blue wire from the fan?

Tags: wiring, ceiling-fan

I have installed a ceiling fan with a light kit and remote control. I connected all the wires as per instructions but, there is a red wire coming from the box that is extra. I connected it to the blue wire coming from the receiver and the blue wire on the fan motor. I have two wall switches, one for light and one for fan. Everything works fine but, I am worried about the connection of the red wire causing an electrical fire in the future because I know it is a 'hot' wire and I just guessed at what to do with it. Should I have just capped it off?

Answer (score 1):

You should have capped it, or connected it to either the black or blue from the ceiling fan only.  The remote receiver takes power from the switch (black and white input leads), and outputs power to the light (blue output lead), the fan (black output lead), or both.

With the black wire from the ceiling connected to the receiver, one of the switches will supply power to the receiver. With the red from the ceiling connected to the receiver, the other switch would power the receiver.

If you connected the black wire from the ceiling to the receiver, and the red wire from the ceiling to the black wire from the ceiling fan. One switch would control the receiver,  and the other would control the fan. In this case the black (output) wire from the receiver should be capped off.

If you connected the black wire from the ceiling to the receiver, and the red wire from the ceiling to the blue wire from the ceiling fan.  One switch would Connell the receiver, and the other would control the lights.  In this case the blue (output) wire from the receiver should be capped off.